# iOS MPMoviePlayerViewController stop playing when screen locks

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode5

I implement MPMoviePlayerViewController to play video and I enable airPlay and works great but the problem is when the screen on the ipad locks. My question is how can make sure the MPMoviePlayerViewController still in airPlay even when the screen locks. Any of you knows how can I make this work?

Comment: try this may it will work..    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

Comment: as I mention before I using MPMoviePlayerViewController not AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Where as Apple thinks that When user can't see the video what is the benefit to runs consistently? So there is no need to play Video when you can't see it. Apple pauses it when app goes to background or screen locks. If you still want to play it you can add notification to start and stop when you go to background and come to foreground.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your Info.plist file, add the key "Required background modes" with the value "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay".

Also, when you receive the notification MPMoviePlayerIsAirPlayVideoActiveDidChangeNotification, add these lines:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

And add this line to your dealloc method:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
```